# redirecting stdout within screen command

Tags: bash

I want to redirect stdout and run command in screen. For example I have simple command:

```
echo yo | tee yo.log
```

and now I want to run it within screen:

```
screen -dmS screenName echo yo | tee yo.log
```

which doesn't work because pipe will redirect screen output, not my command(echo). How can I fix it to see in my file output of echo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

screen -dm bash -c "echo yo | tee yo.log"

Found on [this thread](https://superuser.com/a/454909)

Comment: The key here (and this is all over SO in various questions) is that the `|` needs to be *inside* the command run by screen and not seen by the shell that runs `screen`.

Comment: Sorry, not working, neither output is being redirected

Comment: @m0skit0 Could open a question on SO so we can take a look at your specific case?

Comment: Hmm - this is a shame, was hoping to redirect a screen serial monitor through a local command.